# Integrals and area of circle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I have no idea where to start this one guys:

Write a definite integral whose value is the area of the region between the two circles:

$$x^2+y^2=1$$
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$

Do I need to find my intersection points and then the integrals?

Comment: start with sketching each circle, and find the points where they intersect (by solving the two equations simultaneously),this will give you the limits of the integral. It might be $\int dx$ or $\int dy$ or perhaps $\int d\theta$ (polar coordinates) depending on how the two circles intersect, that would be most suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Easy way

Area is given by $$A=4\int_{1/2}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

---

> Hard way

By solving these two equations for $x$ we find that they Intersect at $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Area is given by $$A=2\left[\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\,\mathrm dx+\int_{1/2}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\right]$$

hope you can proceed from here

> Here's graphical explanation of multiplying by $2$

[image]

Comment: in fact the area is $4\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{1-x^2} dx.$

Comment: @Inetgrator, you don't need the second integral. second is the same as the first one by symmetry.

Comment: @Inegrator, don't matter. beginner or not. anyone can see the two areas are the same.

Comment: @abel but if you remove the second explanation, then no-one would be able to see that the second and the first are the same, since there will be no second :)

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko, once you have the picture, it is not a big jump, even for a beginner, to see that the second integral is not needed there. as a teaching tool it is horrible to put up convoluted integral just because you can do so. by the way, you don't need any calculus to do this. basic area of a sector and triangle will just do.

Comment: It's easier to integrate with respect to $y$, which only has one integral

Comment: I actually found the graph one ("hard" way) to be more intuitive and easier, but whatever.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me $\int dy$ might work better. 
So, start with sketching each circle, and find the points where they intersect (by solving the two equations simultaneously). One circle is centered at the origin, the other at $(1,0)$, each has radius 1. They intersect when $x=\frac12$, $y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ (look at the nice picture that @Integrator posted in their answer, $A(\frac12,\frac{-\sqrt{3}}2)$, $B(\frac12,\frac{\sqrt{3}}2)$). Instead of splitting the integrals as @Integrator did into two integrals (which is fine), you could get away with doing just one integral $\int\limits_{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}2}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}...dy$, but then  you need to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$ each of the two equations, and pick a suitable branch in each case. From the first equation you get $x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$, use the $+$ branch as the "curve at the right". From the second $x=1\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$, use the $-$ branch as the "curve at the left". So then compute 
$\int\limits_{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}2}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2}\sqrt{1-y^2}-(1-\sqrt{1-y^2})\ dy= \int\limits_{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}2}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}2} 2\sqrt{1-y^2}-1\ dy$. You should get the same answer both ways, using the integral in the answer by @integrator, or using the integral in my answer.

Though ... @Integrator (with help from @abel) beat me, found a way to do just one integral even with $\int...dx$ :) And, just for the record, the integrals (either answer) evaluate to $\frac{2\pi}3-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ .

Answer (score 1):

Just make a sketch first if you cannot figure it out at first,after sketching you will see clearly what is going on.